# Mercurial hg(v4) get trunk commits since given revision

Tags: mercurial

The screenshot shows that hg(v2) can get trunk only commits since a particular revision. In the example below, **rev 1** is not a trunk commit.
[image: trunk commits]
How do we get trunk only commits since given rev in hg v4?

- To create the hg test repository used here, run the following:

```
$ mkdir hg-multi-branch
$ cd hg-multi-branch
$ hg init
$ v=A && touch $v && hg add $v && hg commit -m "Added $v"
$ hg branch feature
$ v=B && touch $v && hg add $v && hg commit -m "Added $v"
$ hg co default
$ v=C && touch $v && hg add $v && hg commit -m "Added $v"
```

One could use the **-b default** opt to get commits from the default branch. However using **-b** is not exactly the same as **--follow-parent**. There are cases where the output would be different.

Comment: You can can use `-b` and `--follow-parent` flags together. Something like `hg log -b default --folow-parent`.

Comment: Pls, read next time *before asking* `hg help revsets` + `hg help templating` and grok differences between `:` and `::` ranges. BTW, `--follow-first` is useless in your use case

Comment: Pulkit, I need to make `hg log -r upto:after` work for this example. My actual use case has variable upto/after values. For the given example using hg(v4) `hg log -r 2:2 --follow-parent -b default` returns 2 revs, which is incorrect. hg(v2) correctly returned a single rev.

Answer (score 0):

as @Lazy-Badger said `::` range should work for you

`hg log --follow-first -r 0::tip`

> all changesets that are descendants of x and ancestors of y, including x and y themselves.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets